# Find client name for gRPC call in Go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

I have used protobufs to define my models and gRPC service, and generated protos for Go (.pb.go). When I make gRPC call to a service, I want to find out in server the name of the client/application calling the server API. 
Can the context parameter in the API be of any help here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`WithUserAgent`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#WithUserAgent) dial option to set a custom user agent string on the client.

For retrieving the user agent on the server side, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753461/how-can-i-get-the-client-ip-address-and-user-agent-in-golang-grpc#comment90466921_51753461). It's not fully answered, but you can just print the metadata map and see how the user agent gets stored in the metadata. And then post your findings there :)

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you can use [GRPC Metadata](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md). It's not strong typed (because it's just `map[string][]string`), but may fit your needs good. Set custom metadata field on client side and check this field in server handler.